# ArcGIS Android negative feature OID

Tags: esri-geodatabase, features, android, feature-layer, arcgis-android

I am attempting to add a feature to an existing feature layer hosted on the ArcGIS for developers website. However, when I attempt to apply edits to the map, it does not ever actually add it, and when I print out the ID it is -10. Here is my initialization:

```
gFST = new GeodatabaseFeatureServiceTable(mFeatureServiceURL, 0);
mFeatl = new FeatureLayer(gFST);
mMapView.addLayer(mFeatl);
```

When I click an addNew button, it calls this code:

```
Point point = mMapView.getLocationDisplayManager().getPoint();
GeodatabaseFeature gFeat = new GeodatabaseFeature(atts, point, gFST);
long fid = gFST.addFeature(gFeat);
Log.e(TAG, "ADDED fid: " + fid + " and string: " + gFST.getFeature(fid).toString());
gFST.applyEdits(new CallbackListener<List<GeodatabaseEditError>>() {
                @Override
                public void onCallback(List<GeodatabaseEditError> geodatabaseEditErrors) {
                    Log.e(TAG, "In callback, successfull");
                }

                @Override
                public void onError(Throwable throwable) {
                    Log.e(TAG, "CALLBACK error after applying edits");
                }
```

The log message that prints out is:

```
dummy_test.MainActivity﹕ ADDED fid: -10 and string: GeodatabaseFeature [geometry=Point [m_attributes=[-9676958.5842, 4933326.738700001], m_description=com.esri.core.geometry.VertexDescription@7c5d0f85], attributes={CONDITION=null, GlobalID={5B1244C6-1DA8-49EC-B568-476DB9C1DBBD}, HEIGHT=null, OBJECTID=-10, TREETYPE=maple}, table=GeodatabaseFeatureTable [Name=ArAGATS.XXX.XXX, ID=0, geodatabase=Geodatabase [gdbPath=/data/data/com.example.XXX.dummy_test/cache/GeodatabaseTempFolder/FeatureServiceTable-1586046028.geodatabase]], oid=-10]
```

It doesnt seem like the ID should be negative, and when I run this both the onCallback and onError functions are called, and the feature does not appear to be added to the map. Has anyone experienced something like this or see any glaring errors in what I'm doing?

EDIT: Additionally, none of the features from the online feature layer are showing up on my map. although from printouts I have it appears to be connecting to the url and creating a local geodatabase.